# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Musical Practice & Performance Stack Exchange](http://music.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Walking bass line over an auxiliary diminished scale](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14348/walking-bass-line-over-an-auxiliary-diminished-scale)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Trumpet improv harmonics?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14813/trumpet-improv-harmonics)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Chord notation for stacked and inverted chords or intervals?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14997/chord-notation-for-stacked-and-inverted-chords-or-intervals)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Am/C guitar chord help](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14547/am-c-guitar-chord-help)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Training muscle memory without focusing. Is it necessarily bad?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14360/training-muscle-memory-without-focusing-is-it-necessarily-bad)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to get rid of nasality in singing](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14400/how-to-get-rid-of-nasality-in-singing)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- ['Fine' at the end of the song](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14825/fine-at-the-end-of-the-song)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to calculate the tempo of a song in numbers and find the Italian terms?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14982/how-to-calculate-the-tempo-of-a-song-in-numbers-and-find-the-italian-terms)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Playing Sax and Clarinet](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14477/playing-sax-and-clarinet)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [what is causing this buzzing sound on my A string](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14355/what-is-causing-this-buzzing-sound-on-my-a-string)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---